# If this possible to convert geoJson to KML file and export it in react native?

Tags: javascript, react-native, geospatial, geojson, kml

Hi everyone I need to convert geoJson data to KML file and export it in React native, Is this possible, and how do I do it, This possible to implement only front-end (or have any open API to solve this feature?)

Answer (score 0):

to convert a geoJson file to kml i used the [`tokml`](https://github.com/mapbox/tokml) library
to download it works using the [`react-native-fs`](https://github.com/itinance/react-native-fs) library

Answer (score 0):

Use `tokml` library & Follow given steps

1. install tokml package by using this command `npm install tokml`
2. 

```js
import tokml from 'tokml';

const geoJsonData = {
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "features": [{
    "type": "Feature",
    "geometry": {
      "type": "Point",
      "coordinates": [102.0, 0.5]
    },
    "properties": {
      "name": "Dinagat Islands"
    }
  }]
};

const kmlData = tokml(geoJsonData);
console.log(kmlData);
```